# How to control breadcrumbs in Kallyas / WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

how can I control the behaviour of the breadcrumbs in the Kallyas theme? There's no options neither in version 3.6 of the Kallyas theme nor in version 2.2.10 of Woocommerce. My problem is actually that the appearance of breadcrumbs is not really homogeneous:

- Using "Custom Header Layout" header (Page builder): Breadcrumbs visible
  (shows option for showing or not showing breadcrumbs)
- Using "Static Content Default" header (Page builder): Breadcrumbs not visible

Sometimes I need the "Static Content Layout" Header, sometimes the other. I just cannot accept that I have to chose the one or the other in order to have a breadcrumb or not.

In Woocommerce, breadcrumbs only start at product level, the category level shows no breadcrumbs, so yet another open question to me.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions on how to control the beast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kallayas, as many other themes that use visual builders, is suffering from a lot of usability issues. If you know a bit of PHP, I'd suggest you use Yoast SEO with the breadcrumbs feature (Advanced menu in admin panel). There could be a lot of other good solutions, but this one works great for me.

Kallayas did some major change of their code from version 3 to 4, which created way too much work for us when updating a client's site, so be aware of this, if you happen to be still using it.

P.S. I'm aware I'm answering a 3-year old question, I just hope that this could help anyone else struggling with breadcrumbs with Kallayas.